# How to append a non-breaking space in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a WinForms project where I am entering Persian text into a TextBox control. I have seen   usage in HMTL pages. However what I need here is I want to set a keyboard shortcut so when the shortcut key is pressed, the TextBox appends a non-breaking space to the text and the user can continue entering the rest. This element,  , really matters for some languages like Persian as you could see in the following:

Normal Text:

کتابخانه های الکترونیکی

With Non-breaking Space :

کتابخانه‌های الکترونیکی

How can I use that in WinForms?

Comment: But two words are same .what do you mean?

Comment: use a RichTextBox instead? Especially with use of shortcuts.

Comment: @mohsen They are not the same specially when doing a Search. Non-breaking space is NOT a full space.

Comment: Do you want prevent to enter them when pressing shortcut ?

Comment: Which shortcut will enter Non-breaking space ?

Comment: I see what you want but I don't see where the problem might be? You need to decide on a short-cut, catch it and insert the nbrsp at the SelectionStart of the TextBox. Sounds straight forward. Did you try?

Comment: @mohsen Have a look at the accpeted answer. [What is NBSP](http://andisheh-ta.blogfa.com/post-231.aspx) and [How to set a shortcut for it in MS Word](http://adabiatema.com/index.php/2012-06-18-09-49-49/2012-06-20-14-14-51/163-negahe-no/1063-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the `KeyPress` event  and insert the character you want at the insertion point like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space &&
        ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {
        char nbrsp = '\u2007';                 // non-breaking space
        char zerospace = '\u200B';            // zero space
        char zerospacenobinding = '\u200C';  //zero space no character binding
        char zerospacebinding = '\u200D';   // zero space with character binding

        int s = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(s, nbrsp.ToString() );
        e.Handled = true;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = s + 1;
    }
}
```

Note that while [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) uses I  `Ctl-Shift-Space`this combination also may switch between `Right-To-Left` and `Left-To-Right`. So let's use `Ctrl-Space` insteadt.

Also note that while `KeyDown` does have an `e.Handled` parameter, setting it to `true` does not suppress the character that was entered. So we need to use the `KeyPress` event..

Comment: This direct answer did NOT work. When using that I just received normal space for nbrsp and a decendent of 'i' for slimnbrsp. However, the trick I used was this: I typed a nbsp in Microsft word, copied it into a string variable and replaced it for nbrsp.toString(). Well, it now works just as I want it. Thankyou.

Comment: There is also one other thing that I'd better mention. It seems i mistakenly used NBSP instead of [Zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). I'm not still sure though. Hope one can use this answer.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong characted codes. Please see my update. I'm not sure which character you really need nor if you maybe should pick a different short-cut if you go for the binding-zero-space..

Comment: Btw: I find that the Windows Tools program CharacterMap is very useful to find key and their codes.

Comment: I understand as this normally matters in languages like Persian. This one also does not work, because I get a square for the shortcut. I'll have to stick to the comment I mentioned earlier. Only problem now is that my language is RTL but when hitting Ctrl+Shift textBox goes LTR. Couldn't re-RTL it through code.

Comment: Hm, are you sure your font supports all characters you need? - Do you maen that the shortcut switches the RTL to LTR??? That would be really weirs! And you can't do a `textBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;` ?? Maybe you can use the RightToLeftChanges event?

Comment: [Intro to the character](https://i.imgsafe.org/95db871.png) and [result from your code](https://i.imgsafe.org/9764659.png). `textBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;` didn't work, I also tried `textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;`.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't do that here; but them I'm on a German windows/keyboard... See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/321037/how-to-untoggle-right-to-left-text-in-notepad) for a (confusing) discussion.. If that shortcut is not feasible do pick something else then; the checks are rather plain to modify but which to pick is not. Ctl-Space comes to mind, but I'm not really sure if nothing else might use it. But as long as the focus is in the TextBox it could be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112755/discussion-between-medise-and-taw).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `KeyPress` event and then for example if the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, replace the space with a `\u200B` character:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar==' ' && ModifierKeys== Keys.Control)
            e.KeyChar='\u200B';
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```